# WordPress: Updating via Import

Tags: import, bulk-import

If I use the WordPress import feature avaialbale at

```
Tools -> Import
```

with a WordPress export file that contains the following

```
<wp:category>
    <wp:category_nicename><![CDATA[magento]]></wp:category_nicename>
    <wp:cat_name><![CDATA[Magento]]></wp:cat_name>
</wp:category>
```

WordPress will create a category.  The category's name will be Magento, and its slug/nicename will be `magento`.  However, if I attempt to import a second file with a slightly edited name

```
<wp:category>
    <wp:category_nicename><![CDATA[magento]]></wp:category_nicename>
    <wp:cat_name><![CDATA[Magento Ecommerce]]></wp:cat_name>
</wp:category>
```

It (seems like?) WordPress will **not** update the category name. i.e. You can use the import files to create new categories, but not edit new categories.

Is there a way to configure WordPress's import XML files such that an entry for a category (or post, or taxonomy term) will be updated **without** needing to know the numerical ID of the category?  I'm mainly wondering if this exists for core WordPress, but feel free to also recommend plugins/extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import can be used for adding new "items" to wordpress, but not changing existing ones. If you want to update anything you should use the xml-rpc protocol with the relevant commands https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API, or if you need it only locally wpcli http://wp-cli.org/ might be even better (never used it for your specific type of change but I assume you can do it with it)